# How to correctly merge observable streams (from Firestore) in angular. Effectively a logical OR

Tags: angular, rxjs, google-cloud-firestore

I am performing multiple Firestore queries with dynamic query parameters in an attempt to merge them all and get an effective logical OR output.

So, in a for loop, I am collecting all of the database query outputs into an array and then using the spread operator to merge them all together.

Everything appears to work just as intended - if I subscribe to the single merged observable and log output, I am getting output from different individual queries!

The problem arises in the HTML when I pipe the single merged observable to async and attempt to use ngFor to iterate over the individual items. It acts as if the observable is empty.

*.ts:

```
private getMergedEvents(queryParameters: string[]){
    let observables: Observable<any[]>[] = [];
    let temp_observable: Observable<any[]>;

    //Loop through the list of bills and build dynamic queries
    queryParameters.forEach((bill, index) =>{
      temp_observable =
        this.db.collection(
          'daily_file/',
          ref => ref.where('bill_ids.' + bill, '==', true)
        ).valueChanges()

      //Use a temporary array and merge afterwards for clarity.
      observables[index] = temp_observable;
    })

    //Merge all of the observables to combine into one
    this.eventObservables = Observable.merge(...observables)
    this.eventObservables.subscribe(events =>{
      for(let event of events) {
        console.log(event.date)
      }
    })
  }
```

Output:
[image]

*.html:

```
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let event of eventObservables | async">
      <h1>static text</h1>
      <h1>{{event.date}}</h1>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

As stated above, nothing is displayed on the screen (not even the static text) indicating that the observable is empty.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You're subscribing twice to the same observable, and observables are not multicast by default. You could use a Subject to achieve that result, or create a multicast observable as described here: http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-multicast

Comment: I tried just removing the programmatic call to subscribe (which just logged for debugging purposes anyways) and still got the same behavior :(
For investigation purposes I then added the log statement back in and actually duplicated the subscribe call (with the log) and it printed out all items twice. Maybe Firestore returns a multicast observable by default?

Comment: By the way you're using a ion-item component and transclusion. Do you have a ng-content directive in the template of that ion-item component?